On the use of overtly
I need help settling a debate over the way in which I used the word 'overtly' today. A friend and I have been going back and forth over it so I figure let's get a third (or fourth) opinion on it.
Today I said, "I would not be overtly surprised if she was forced to do it". While I understand that the normal/common phrase that people are familiar with would be "I would not be overly surprised...", that is not what I was going for.
Admittedly I didn't know the full meaning of the word, which is "without concealment or secrecy; openly.", however, I feel that it is okay to use 'overtly' in this way as not only is it grammatically correct, but it also makes sense semantically. My interpenetration of it after learning the meaning is along the lines of "I would be openly surprised..." as the word surprise does not necessarily mean that it is obvious when someone is surprised.
The foundation of my friends counter-argument is that the use of the word 'overtly' is redundant as 'surprise' would mean that it was already obvious and without concealment.
Granted, this is a silly thing to argue about, but it does have me wondering.

Curiously “overtly surprised” appears to be more commonly used in recent years: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overtly+surprised&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3

You say your meaning is "I would be openly surprised," but your words add up to "I would not be openly surprised."

You've got me there. I'm trying to convey that I would be able to hide my surprise fairly easily as it would be an underwhelming level of surprise. I must admit my comprehension is terrible at the best of times. Regardless, my meaning shouldn't matter hopefully, as we're just trying to determine if it is an appropriate way to use the word grammatically and semantically.

It's either unidiomatic, which can be worse than ungrammatical, or a whimsical usage, inappropriate in formal registers. 'I would not be noticeably surprised' is a little better, but 'I would not be so surprised that it would show' seems far more natural.

Sorry if you feel your meaning shouldn't matter. It does.

I'm not sure I understand why my intended meaning would matter, if what we're trying to figure out is whether the sentence on its own makes sense grammatically and semantically.

Your use of "interpenetration" instead of "interpretation" tells a very similar story to that of using "overtly" where "overly" is commonly used. It makes me wonder if you're either glossing over differences between similar looking words, or retroactively trying to justify this usage to avoid having to admit a mistake.

I mean, I can admit my English skills are sub-par. I'm not afraid of being wrong. Thanks for noticing a typo there though! In this case it was a verbal conversation, not a online chat somewhere where I could have made a typo, and I absolutely meant to use the word 'overtly'.

So you didn't know what "overtly" meant but you used it in a sentence. Your friend challenged you on it, you found out what it meant, and now that is what you were going for all along? Just admit you made a mistake.

I'd say that overtly is a malapropism as you're using it. The idiomatic way to say that surprise  would not be written all over your face is:

I would show no surprise if she was forced to do it.

But that doesn't make much sense, does it?  What weird situation would put the look on your face at the center of  a situation where someone was being forced to do something?
This isn't to say that overtly couldn't be used in that manner, just that the context you've supplied doesn't really support it. If you say it does, fine, but you're expecting the person you're speaking with to read your mind because the utterance alone doesn't express anything that would justify that meaning.

When meeting with them, be sure to act overtly surprised when they tell you about their plans to sell off that subsidiary.  We wouldn't want them to know we have a mole in their C-suite.

But even there overtly is not needed. It is otiose.  "act surprised" is the idiomatic phrase, and everyone understands it to mean that the person is evincing surprise, showing it on their facial expression, in their body language, in how they respond vocally, whatever.

This appears to be a malapropism for "I would not be overly surprised." Drop the t.

No, they say specifically that they mean "overtly", as in showing the surprise, not "overly".

If that's what they mean, it's an uncommon phrase, likely to be misunderstood as the more common one, and probably better avoided. "Real writers rewrite to avoid the problem."

Indeed so, exactly as I just recommended in my own answer.

"I'm trying to convey that I would be able to hide my surprise fairly easily," could be described as being covertly surprised.

But isn't usually.


I feel that it is okay to use 'overtly' in this way as not only is it grammatically correct, but it also makes sense semantically.

What you seem to have meant is that you would not show surprise, though you might nevertheless feel it. Your wording indeed is grammatically correct and indeed does mean that.  Nevertheless, you should not use that wording because

There is a high risk of your audience assuming that you have used the wrong word -- "overtly" when you meant "overly" -- because "overly surprised" is fairly common, whereas "overtly surprised" is very uncommon, at best.  Personally, I would speak in terms of "showing" surprise, as I did above, to avoid the risk of such a misinterpretation.

The nature of surprise is that you might not actually be able to control your immediate reaction.  If you can predict with confidence that you would not show surprise under certain circumstances, then it seems like you are saying that you would not be surprised under those circumstances in the first place.  If that's what you mean, then you should say it directly.


Perhaps (2) is what your friend was going for, but it's not what you described their position to be.  Surprise is often accompanied by a visible reaction, but it is not the reaction itself.  You can definitely be surprised without showing it.
